# Error while creating bundle from Jar

Tags: jar, osgi, aem, manifest.mf

I am converting jar into OSGI bundle using command jar cvfm test5.jar manifest.txt IngrianNAE-8.4.2.000.p02.jar.
 When I am adding 'Export-Package' in the manifest file the bundle does not get created and I get following error:

```
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:410)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:176)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

If I remove the Export-Package or place its tag at the end of manifest file, the bundle gets created but Export-Packages are not visible in the created bundle when I deploy it on AEM. with the following manifest file: Manifest-Version: 1.0

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1527751846288
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_161
Built-By: 312847
Bundle-Description: Test
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: test
Bundle-Version: 1.1.1.4
Export-Package: com.ingrian.security.nae
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you use Intellij Ultimate 2020.1:
I disabled all osgi plugins in Settings->Plugins

Answer (score -1):

You are missing out on `Bundle-ClassPath: .,test5.jar` entry in the manifest.mf file. This essentially embeds the original jar as-is in the created bundle, thereby making the export packages available.

Also ensure `com.ingrian.security.nae` is a valid package available in `test5.jar`.

Detailed info on how to create a bundle from jar file [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/ConvertAJarIntoOsgiBundle.html) and you can find info on how to structure manifest files [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).